# Listening for changes on Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure on my firebase database:

```
{
  "gateways_pr" :{
    "gateway_1":{
        "avisos" : {
            "00":{
                "aviso_1" : "0",
                "aviso_2" : "0"
            },
            "01":{
                "aviso_1" : "0",
                "aviso_2" : "0"
            }

        }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a small demo javascript webPage that is listening to child_change in gateways_pr/gateway_1/avisos:

```
var gateWayRef = firebase.database().ref("gateways_pr/gateway_1/avisos");


gateWayRef.on('child_changed',function(data){
  console.log("CHILD_CHANGE");
  console.log(data.val()); 
  var datos = data.val(); 
  console.log(datos);
});
```

When I changed for example gateway_1/avisos/00/aviso_1 and set it to 2 I can track the change with chrome developer tools looking into the frames of the websocket and I receive:

```
{"t":"d","d":{"b":{"p":"gateways_pr/gateway_1/avisos/00/aviso_1","d":"2"},"a":"d"}}
```

So I´m only receiving the change made.

The problem is that, on my code, data.val() has the following value:

```
{aviso_1: "2", aviso_2: "0"}
```

Calling data.ref.path.toString() returns :

```
/gateways_pr/gateway_1/avisos/00
```

That means that the Firebase API shows you everything below the children that had it´s property changed (00 in this case).

it´s there anyway of knowing what was the change (in this case should return "aviso_1")?

The only workaround I´ve found so far is making my code to listen on every child. In this case I should listen to gateways_pr/gateway_1/avisos/00 and gateways_pr/gateway_1/avisos/01, but if I add new entries to "avisos" I should start listening to them too, and at the end my program could end listening to thousand of referecenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach a `child_changed` listener to `gateways_pr/gateway_1/avisos`, you're asking the Firebase client to inform you when something changes in a child under that level. If something changes on a lower level, the Firebase client will raise the `child_changed` event on the level that you registered for. There is no way to change this behavior.

When you have the need to know precisely what changed under the listener, it typically means that you've modeled the data wrong for your use-case.

For example: if you want to listen for changes across the entire hierarchy, you should model a list of changes across the entire hierarchy and then attach a listener to that list. This is one of the many reasons that the Firebase documentation recommends keeping flat data structures.